# SQLite Open Helper creates empty db

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am so sorry to open a question that has been asked before, but I have already read a lot of replies, tried to change my code to fix it, and I still can't create tables to my SQLite database.

I have also tried to uninstall the app and reinstall, deleted the previous database files to be replace, and the output is always the same.

This is my Open Helper class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Dados.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

    private String primeiraquery = "create table Informacoes (Identificacao VARCHAR(255))";
    Context context;

    public DataBaseClass(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(primeiraquery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Changing the query to add ' ' or no space between the table name and () also produced the same output.

And this is MainActivity.class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.appname.DataBaseClasses.DataBaseClass;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DataBaseClass database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        database=new DataBaseClass(this);
        createBasedados();
    }

    public void createBasedados(){
        database.getReadableDatabase();
    }
}
```

No matter what, I always get Dados.db with 4KB, and when I open it, it's empty, no tables were created.

Other than that, the databases folder also has Dados.db-shm and Dados.db-wal

I also tried the DatabseHelper from Codebind but once again, the output was always the same, empty file with no tables.

**UPDATE ([2019-06-01 17:29:24Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56408563/sqlite-open-helper-creates-empty-db#comment99415128_56408563)):**

@CommonWares pointed out that

> Are you copying all of the files, or are you just copying the .db file? You need all of them.

I was just copying the `.db` file. After copying all of the 3, I can now see the tables of the database, instead of an empty file.

Comment: "and when I open it" -- how are you doing this?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm using DB Browser for SQLite, but I also used an online SQLite Browser, and the file is empty in both

Comment: Switch to `getWriteableDatabase()` and see if you have different behavior.

Comment: @CommonsWare Same behavior, unfortunately

Comment: You are using DB Browser for SQLite to open which database? Do you extract it from the device?

Comment: @forpas The one I created. Yes! Device File Explorer > data > com.example.appname > databases

Comment: If you have this line: `android:allowBackup="true"` in the manifest, change it to `android:allowBackup="false"` and then rerun, uninstall and rerun.

Comment: @forpas I don't have it. Should I add it and set it as false?

Comment: The default value is true, so set `android:allowBackup="false"`  and then rerun, uninstall and rerun.

Comment: Are you copying *all* of the files, or are you just copying the `.db` file? You need all of them.

Comment: @forpas I did set it as false. Rerun, uninstall, rerun again. Same output, I don't know why...

Comment: @CommonsWare I was just copying the .db files, I just copied all of the 3 and now I can see the tables... Thank you so much, I though they were temporary and didn't keep the structure of the table

Answer (score -1):

Please try this :

1.maybe create table Informacoes need id primary key

2. change VARCHAR(255) to varchar
3. change  DATABASE_VERSION=1;  to  DATABASE_VERSION=2;

   public class DataBaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   ```
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Dados.db";
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=2;

   private String primeiraquery = "create table Informacoes (_id integer primary key autoincrement,Identificacao varchar)";
   Context context;

   public DataBaseClass(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
       this.context=context;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       db.execSQL(primeiraquery);
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

   }
   ```

   }

Comment: this is the valid SQL query

Comment: I believe VARCHAR requires that I specify the size, and this table in particular doesn't require an id since it will only have one line...
I did change VERSION to 2, but It still produced an empty file

Comment: I also replaced my query with yours, but the final file is still empty, no table created